# Why is C# List<T> Add method very slow?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, dapper, generic-list

I have an ASP.NET MVC project using Dapper to read data from a database and I need to export to Excel.

Dapper is fast! `ExecuteReader` takes only 35 seconds.

But `list.Add(InStock);` spends too much time!  Over 1020 seconds!

Do you have any idea why this is?

```cs
public List<InStock> GetList(string stSeId, string edSeId, string stSeDay, string edSeDay, string qDate)
{
    List<InStock> list = new List<InStock>();
    InStock InStock = null;

    IDataReader reader;

    using (var conn = _connection.GetConnection())
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            //******************Only 35 seconds*****
            reader = conn.ExecuteReader(fileHelper.GetScriptFromFile("GetInStock"),
                 new { STSeId = stSeId, EDSeId = edSeId, STSeDay = stSeDay, EDSeDay = edSeDay, qDate = qDate });
            //*************************************

            //******************Over 1020 seconds**********
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                InStock = new InStock();

                InStock.ColA = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ColA"));
                InStock.ColB = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ColB"));
                InStock.ColC = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ColC"));

                list.Add(InStock);
            }
            //*********************************************
            return list;
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            throw err;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: My Code In VS Tool]

Comment: There are 5 instructions before the `Add`, are you really sure it's the `Add` method that is taking time?

Comment: @WashingtonA.Ramos Yes sir , I am using breakpoint to count seconds at return list;

Comment: you should use a Performance Profiler (VS has one built in) for that. I really doubt `List<>.Add()` would take that much time.

Comment: @WashingtonA.Ramos OK ! I upload my vs image.

Comment: One thing about your benchmark assumption - you've got an operation involving a database and an operation backed by an in-memory array, and you're pointing at `List<InStock>.Add()` as your performance culprit. Unless the `InStock` ctor is especially intensive, it's the database.

Comment: This question honestly doesnt make sense. How many records are you returning?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ 7351409 rows in Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: Have you tried simply removing the ```.Add ```  line? It must be something else than the list. You could technically initialize the list for a given expected size (```new List(10000)``` , which would improve performance, buf it can't be caused by what you think.

Comment: Based on your code comments and image, it sounds like you're not actually measuring the `.Add()` but rather the entire processing of all 7351409 rows. Also, the call to `conn.ExecuteReader` probably isn't loading all the results immediately, but relies on `reader.Read()` to do this. This would explain the disparity between the two.

Comment: 7351,409 rows within less than a second. Hmm... I would be happy! This is not a bad result when the test team revises your code. Btw: `reader.GetString()` and `Reader.Read()` is way slower than `List.Add()`.

Comment: Under a debugger is not when you want to be timing your code in the first place, and I'm not familiar with Dapper but I agree the call to `ExecuteReader()` shouldn't actually be reading anything so it's not a fair comparison.  Do you even need to return a complete `List<>` of that many results instead of `yield return`ing an `IEnumerable<>`?  By the way, be aware that `catch (Exception err) { throw err; }` will mask the source of `err`; either change it to just `throw;` or remove the `catch` entirely.  Now, about that Comic Sans...

Comment: @BACON Thank you ! Thanks to everyone who leave comment to me. I learned so much form you !! But I still don't know is there a way to create excel report with large data ??

Comment: A minor optimization would be to move the three ```reader.GetOrdinal``` calls out of the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's the database.**

From [Retrieve data using a DataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader),

> The DataReader is a good choice when you're retrieving large amounts of data because the data is not cached in memory.

The key clue for your performance concern regards "because the data is not cached in memory". While strictly an implementation detail, each call to `Read()` gets new data from the database, while the `List<InStock>.Add()` call is just adding the new `InStock` to the list.

There are orders of magnitude of difference in processing times between disk access (even SSDs) compared to RAM. And theres orders of magnitude of difference between network requests and disk access. There's not really a conceivable way that anything other than the database access is the cause of most of your run time.

--

As a side note, you're going to exceed the [maximum number of rows](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) in an Excel worksheet.

Comment: Sir I am very appreciated !! But what is the best way to create report with large data ?

Comment: I've been lucky enough to have ready access to real reporting tools over the years. Based on the short code snippet you've got it's really hard to say (as it is, you're just dumping all the rows to the report). How to make a report really is a separate question.